# Crosstab Query Formula

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having issues to understand how I can make this work. I require the formula to check if `DocumentType` is changed then calculate for that `MemberID` using that `MemberShare` and `SumofMemberShare` only.

Currently, it displays for all even if the `MemberID` is not a part of that `DocumentType`. Please help.

I tried this formula and it does not calculate the DocumentType JPA1 values

MemberCost: Sum(IIf([TestingProjectWPTable Query].[DocumentType]=[TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY].[DocumentType],Nz([TestingProjectWPTable Query].[CurrentBudget]*[TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY].[MemberShare]/[Total Share],0),0))

Sample data

| ProjecID | WPNumber | WPName | DocumentType | CurrentBudget | TotalShare | WikCredit | MemberID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JP2001 | 80000 | ProjectDev | JPP | $15,000 | 10.5 |  |  |
| JP2001 | 81000 | ProjectMgmnt | JPP | $25,000 | 10.5 |  |  |
| JP2001 | 82000 | ProjectMgmnt | JPA1 | $45,000 | 13.5 |  |  |

MEMBER Table

| ProjecID | DocumentType | MemberID | MemberShare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JP2001 | JPP | 11 | 5.5 |
| JP2001 | JPP | 2 | 4.0 |
| JP2001 | JPP | 9 | 1.0 |
| JP2001 | JPA1 | 7 | 2.0 |
| JP2001 | JPA1 | 8 | 1.0 |

JPP Total Member Share 10.5
JPA Total Member Share 13.5

SQL

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![APLTBLFRM]![ProjectID] Long;
TRANSFORM Sum(Nz([CurrentBudget]*[MemberShare]/[Total Share],0)) AS MemberCost
SELECT [TestingProjectWPTable Query].ProjectID, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WPNumber, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WPName, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].DocumentType, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].CurrentBudget, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].SumOfSumOfMemberShare AS [Total Share], [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WiKCredit, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].MemberID
FROM TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY INNER JOIN [TestingProjectWPTable Query] ON TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY.ProjectID = [TestingProjectWPTable Query].ProjectID
WHERE (((TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY.ProjectID)=[Forms]![APLTBLFRM]![ProjectID]))
GROUP BY [TestingProjectWPTable Query].ProjectID, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WPNumber, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WPName, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].DocumentType, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].CurrentBudget, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].SumOfSumOfMemberShare, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].WiKCredit, [TestingProjectWPTable Query].MemberID
ORDER BY [TestingProjectWPTable Query].DocumentType DESC 
PIVOT [TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY].[MemberName] & ", Share " & [TestProjectCostFieldsJPPQRY].[MemberShare];
```

[Output View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Oe9.jpg)

Thanks,
Taruna

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. I don't see any formula that does a 'check'. The 'error' image does not clarify.

Comment: @June7 I am not sure how to add table I tried doing that also attached the output view

Comment: Again, please indicate the attempt at formula. Your SQL does not show it and output of results does not emphasize it. What do you mean by *check if DocumentType is changed*.

Comment: @Parfait I added the formula above. DocumentType is the Text Field if this differs then the formula should use Total Share and Member Share  for that MemberID Atatched Output View

Comment: Why do you not run the formula in query? You use a different *MemberCost* expression in SQL.

Comment: @Parfait  The formula is part of the in the crosstab query under value. That SQL MemberCost was not giving the desired result that is why I tried the other but that too no luck. Did you check the output view?

Comment: What is output view showing? Desired or undesired results? It looks like Excel not Access output. In 2nd and 3rd paragraphs you mention two issues. Which is it? Are rows dropping before calculation? If so, maybe change join from `INNER` to `LEFT` or `RIGHT`? Sample data of both queries sources would help.

Comment: @Parfait Output view is desired result I did it in excel, I tried adding LEFT /RIGHT and it calculates for  one member. I cannot follow how to add data, is there a way to attach excel file?

Comment: SO does not allow attaching files (other than embedding images). All info to analyze issue should be included in question. If you want to attach files (Excel, Access, etc) try another forum that allows it.

Comment: @June7 I did try adding the dat I am new to this forum so still learning.

Comment: Why is there no MemberID values in sample data table?

Comment: @June7 I provided in the Member table all member related information The information the WikCredit and MemberID is part on the other WP table if applicable.

Comment: The SQL and expression you post use queries, not the tables you posted. What do those queries do? I suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db so ALL information is available for analysis.

Comment: @June7 One is the work package TestingProjectWPTable query other is the Member Query. As suggested by Parfait the LEFT JOIN does the calculation but only for one member, the calculation is correct one.